# Compiling NTL library in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, ntl

I have downloaded NTL version 6.1.0 from http://www.shoup.net/ntl/download.html and having trouble compiling it in Visual Studio 2013. The documentation (http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-win.html) only shows how to compile NTL in MSVC++ 6 which is not working in my case.

I need to use the NTL library to code the prime number in my cryptography project - ElGamal Digital Signature Scheme.

Comment: What exactly are the errors you get?

Comment: The static library template add 4 files by default (pch.h, pch.cpp, <project_name>.h, <project_name>.cpp). And the project structure (It gave me 3 projects in the solution????) is very different from what is discussed in the documentation above.

Comment: The template contains some code to get you started. One on the 3 projects is probably an example (which you also need). But otherwise delete what you don't need. And disable pre-compiled headers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the "File\New\Project From Existing Code..." menu item.
2. In the first page of the "Create New Project from Existing Code Files" wizard, select "Visual C++" in the "What type of project would you like to create?" combo box.
3. Press the Next button.
4. In the next page of the "Create New Project from Existing Code Files" wizard, press the Browse button and select the WinNTL-6_1_0\src directory for the "Project file location."
5. In the "Project Name" edit, type NTL.
6. Press the Next button.
7. In the next page of the "Create New Project from Existing Code Files" wizard, select "Static Library (LIB) project" in the "Project type" combo box.
8. Press the Next button.
9. In the "Include search paths" edit, enter "..\Include."
10. Press the Finish button.

NTL builds, but with warnings.

Comment: If you use Git, I have made available a Git Repository on my BitBucket site that is derived from WinNTL-6_1_0.zip at https://bitbucket.org/ben_key/ntl. I have added the VS2013 project files and resolved over 400 of the warnings I found. I have sent an E-Mail to the author of NTL in the hopes that my changes will be incorporated in the next version of NTL.

I hope this helps.